# Converting JSON Structure to BasicDBObject

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to convert the following `json` structure to `BasicDBOject` in java and insert into mongo db.

My JSON structure is

```
{
    "it": {
        "batch": "2013",
        "students": [
            {
                "name": "joe"
            },
            {
                "name": "john"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

com.mongodb.util.JSON has a parse method.

> BasicDBObject implements DBObject

```
Object o = com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse("Your JSON structure or JSONObj.toString()");
DBObject dbObj = (DBObject) o;
```

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse
> ```
>
> Is deprecated

After version 3.6.1 use:

```
String json = "{"name": "joe"}";
Object o = BasicDBObject.parse(json);
```

Follow here: [deprecated-list](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/deprecated-list.html)